# scrapy - scraping multiple fields

Tags: python, scrapy

very new and inexperienced programmer here!

Am building a scrapy project that can scrape this website for company names and locations and output a JSON file.

https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&page=93&page_alt=1&sort=open

Currently, my scraper is pulling the company names, but is also pulling dates. In addition, the JSON output is coming in sections, first a list of company names then a list of locations (with additional info that I don't want).

How do I just pull the company names / locations and format it so I can associate each company name with the specific location?

I think my issue is that the locations are not defined as a specific class.

In addition, advice on how to set the JSON output format would be greatly appreciated!!

---

**My Project Directory:**

```
`myproject`/
    scrapy.cfg           

    __init__.py

    items.py          

    pipelines.py      

    settings.py       

    spiders/         
        __init__.py
          byub.py
          F6sSpider.py
```

---

**My Spider File:**

```
import scrapy


class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Company"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('div.result-description'):
            yield {
                'program': title.css('div.title a.action.main.noline::text').extract(),
            }
        for subtitle in response.css('div.result-description'):
            yield {
                'location': subtitle.css('div.subtitle span::text').extract(),
            }
```

---

**My Terminal**

```
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: myproject)
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.4.0, Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:23:58) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Darwin-17.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myproject', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'companies.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myproject.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myproject.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1 SeaMonkey/2.7.1'}
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-05-16 13:10:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-05-16 13:10:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.f6s.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-05-16 13:10:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open> (referer: None)
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['K - LAUNCHPAD 2018']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['Z Nation Lab Real Estate Cohort']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['C-mint-International']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['StartOut Growth Lab - 2018 Fall Cohort']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['IBA Application']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['WATT Factory Accelerator Programme 2018']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ["AdvantEdge Founder's Adda"]}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['SpinLab - The HHL Accelerator']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['Shell LiveWIRE Accelerator']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['Shell France Accelerator ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['ELEVATE by TheVentury']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': ['F6S R&D Money Back']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Jun 1-Jul 20                         •\n                    Berlin, Germany    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Mumbai, India    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Atlanta, United States    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Jul 8-Dec 31                         •\n                    San Francisco, United States    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Mar 19-May 16                         •\n                    Los Angeles, United States    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Jun 3-Nov 30                         •\n                    Gent, Belgium    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Delhi, India    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    Leipzig, Germany    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ["\n                    Jun 20 '18-Jun 21  '19                        •\n                    Paris, France    \n                "]}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ["\n                    Jun 20 '18-Jun 1  '19                        •\n                    Paris, France    \n                "]}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ["\n                    Sep 5 '18-Feb 14  '19                        •\n                    Vienna, Austria    \n                "]}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'location': ['\n                    London, United Kingdom    \n                ']}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (24 items) in: companies.json
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 569,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16600,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 16, 12, 10, 32, 32121),
 'item_scraped_count': 24,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 27,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'memusage/max': 49434624,
 'memusage/startup': 49434624,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 16, 12, 10, 30, 500700)}
2018-05-16 13:10:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

---

**My JSON output:**

```
[
{"program": ["K - LAUNCHPAD 2018"]},
{"program": ["Z Nation Lab Real Estate Cohort"]},
{"program": ["C-mint-International"]},
{"program": ["StartOut Growth Lab - 2018 Fall Cohort"]},
{"program": ["IBA Application"]},
{"program": ["WATT Factory Accelerator Programme 2018"]},
{"program": ["AdvantEdge Founder's Adda"]},
{"program": ["SpinLab - The HHL Accelerator"]},
{"program": ["Shell LiveWIRE Accelerator"]},
{"program": ["Shell France Accelerator "]},
{"program": ["ELEVATE by TheVentury"]},
{"program": ["F6S R&D Money Back"]},
{"location": ["\n                    Jun 1-Jul 20                         \u2022\n                    Berlin, Germany    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Mumbai, India    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Atlanta, United States    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Jul 8-Dec 31                         \u2022\n                    San Francisco, United States    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Mar 19-May 16                         \u2022\n                    Los Angeles, United States    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Jun 3-Nov 30                         \u2022\n                    Gent, Belgium    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Delhi, India    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Leipzig, Germany    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Jun 20 '18-Jun 21  '19                        \u2022\n                    Paris, France    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Jun 20 '18-Jun 1  '19                        \u2022\n                    Paris, France    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    Sep 5 '18-Feb 14  '19                        \u2022\n                    Vienna, Austria    \n                "]},
{"location": ["\n                    London, United Kingdom    \n                "]}
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need two `for` loops for that, you can do with one:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.css('div.result-description'):
        yield {
            'program': title.css('div.title a.action.main.noline::text').extract(),
            'location': title.css('div.subtitle span::text').extract(),
        }
```

Comment: When I do this, 0 pages get crawled,  there is an error in terminal and JSON output is blank.

ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 0):

You need to format location in certain cases where date is coming, like this

```
import scrapy

class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Company"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('div.result-description'):
            location = title.css('div.subtitle span::text').extract_first()
            # remove "." from some locations and split by lines
            location = location.encode("ascii","ignore").splitlines()
            # get second last element and remove whitespaces
            location = location[-2].strip()
            yield {
                'program': title.css('div.title a.action.main.noline::text').extract_first(),
                'location': location
            }
```

Output:

```
[{"program": "Z Nation Lab Real Estate Cohort", "location": "Mumbai, India"},
{"program": "C-mint-International", "location": "Atlanta, United States"},
{"program": "StartOut Growth Lab - 2018 Fall Cohort", "location": "San Francisco, United States"},
{"program": "IBA Application", "location": "Los Angeles, United States"},
{"program": "WATT Factory Accelerator Programme 2018", "location": "Gent, Belgium"},
{"program": "AdvantEdge Founder's Adda", "location": "Delhi, India"},
{"program": "SpinLab - The HHL Accelerator", "location": "Leipzig, Germany"},
{"program": "Shell LiveWIRE Accelerator", "location": "Paris, France"},
{"program": "Shell France Accelerator ", "location": "Paris, France"},
{"program": "ELEVATE by TheVentury", "location": "Vienna, Austria"},
{"program": "F6S R&D Money Back", "location": "London, United Kingdom"},
{"program": "2018 StarterStudio Seed Fund Accelerator", "location": "Orlando, United States"}]
```

Comment: What is your run command?

When I run the above, my output returns nothing in it.
In my terminal I am getting the error:

TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

2018-05-17 10:30:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': 'AdTech Istanbul', 'location': b'stanbul, Turkey'}
2018-05-17 10:30:26 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method FeedExporter.item_scraped of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x10889b630>>

Comment: `scrapy crawl Company -o out.json`

Comment: Are you using python3 ? What is your scrapy version?

Comment: using python 3.6, scrapy V 1.5